# Reverse Index/Match -or- jumping back 1 cell in Index/Match

Tags: excel, indexing, match

This started as a just-for-fun formula in a work spreadsheet, but I couldn't figure it out... 
Simplified (hopefully), I have a row with months (Jan-Dec) and a row below with dollar values. For this month (May) I am adding a dollar value. The preceding months have dollar values entered in them already. My formula needs to look across the `$values` row and return the month corresponding to the last cell with an value in it.

Right now Jan-May have `$values`. I want it to stop at the blank `$value` for June, back up one cell and return the month-cell = May.

I have been playing with different `INDEX`/`MATCH`/`LEN` but haven't landed on anything yet. The only thing I thought of that **would** work is nested `IF` statements moving in reverse (Dec -> Jan) looking for the first cell greater than 0. But I'm using an old version and max out at 7 IFs.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something and stumbled on your question. I hope it'll still be somewhat useful!

You probably want:

```
=INDEX(A1:L1,1,COUNTA(A2:L2))
```

Where `A1:L1` contains your months from January to December and `A2:L2` contains the values in dollars. I'm assuming that the values are blank for June through December.